# Append a variable values with string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below string.

```
window.location="./getdata?geo=abc&tab=xyz";
```

Now i have abc and xyz in var as below:

```
var geo="abc";
var tab="xyz";
```

Now how can i append var with above string instead of hard coding them inside a string?

Thanks!

Comment: window.location="./getdata?geo="+geo+"&tab="+tab;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
var geo="abc";
var tab="xyz";

window.location="./getdata?geo=" + geo + "&tab=" + tab;
```

'+' symbol used to concotinate the string

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
window.location="./getdata?geo="+ geo +"&tab=" + tab;
```

And also please read this to know more about [how to do concatenation in Javascript](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp)